# Change submit button text after form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function(event){
        $('#submit').val('Processing …');
        $('SubmitForm').submit();
    });  
});  
</script>
<form  id="SubmitForm" action="/scripts/t.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" data-abide >
 <input  type="submit" value="Submit"  id='submit'>

</form>
```

The following code works in chrome .But it doesn't work in Safari . 
As in when the page is getting submitted the new text is shown in chrome but not in safari.there is no error. The form gets submitted but the text change is not seen .

Can you please guide me. 
~

Comment: Can you use the most recent version of jQuery? `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: As in when the page is geting submitted the new text is shown in chrome but not in safari

Comment: have you checked for error in browser console ?

Comment: there is no error. The form gets submitted but the text change is not seen

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function(event){
        $('#submit').val('Processing …');
        $('SubmitForm').submit();
    });  
  $('form').submit(function(event){
       alert("form submitted");
       $('#submit').val('submitted');
    });
});  
</script>
<form  id="SubmitForm" action="/scripts/t.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" data-abide >
 <input  type="submit" value="Submit"  id='submit'>

</form>
```

Comment: The following code works in chrome .But it doesn't work in Safari . As in when the page is getting submitted the new text is shown in chrome but not in safari.there is no error. The form gets submitted but the text change is not seen .

Answer (score 1):

You can simply modify your `#submit` button value under the form `#SubmitForm` [.submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) event:

```js
$('#SubmitForm').submit((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#submit').attr('value', 'Processing...');
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

<form  id="SubmitForm" action="/scripts/t.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" data-abide >
   <input  type="submit" value="Submit"  id='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: But it doesn't go the action page.

Comment: You can remove the event: e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```html
$('#submit').attr('value', 'new value');
```

Comment: The following code works in chrome .But it doesn't work in Safari . As in when the page is getting submitted the new text is shown in chrome but not in safari.there is no error. The form gets submitted but the text change is not seen .